# confidence intervals or SE of gls {nlme} predicted values

Tags: r, least-squares, predict, confidence-interval, nlme

I'm running a multivariate gls model:

`m <- gls(y ~ x + factor1 + factor2, cor = corPagel(1,phylogeny), weight= ~1/log(n))`

I want to plot the results and I could get predicted values like this:

`newdata <- data.frame(expand.grid( x = mean(x),
                                   factor1= unique(factor1),
                                   factor2 = unique(factor2)))`

`predvals <- predict(m,newdata)`

Although two of the variables I want to plot are factors, and I want to get confidence intervals or standard errors for these predicted values.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance for your help!
Cheers,
Jasmine

Comment: Any data to play with ?

Comment: I think that's a question for stats.stackexchange.com (please flag the question and ask the moderators to migrate it, do not cross-post). Possibly you could use bootstrap? I'm not sure.

Comment: I solved the problem using the "AICcmodavg" package.


`predictSE.gls (model, newdata, se.fit=T)`. It works perfectly!

Comment: But that's the fit interval, not the prediction interval.